# How to save list items on disk instead of memory in Java

Tags: java

I'm looking for a data structure same as ArrayList in Java that saves items on disk instead of memory.
Does java have such a data structure?
Thanks

I want to have a dynamic structure that saves items on memory and when its size exceeds some value, save new items on disk until the size goes below the value.

Answer (score 12):

You can yourself do it: Serialize the `ArrayList` to disk.

Make sure that the contents of the list are serializable, i.e., the objects in the list should implement the `Serializable` interface.

then
**to write to file:**

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
oos.writeObject(list);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
```

**To read from file:**

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
List<YourClass> list = ois.readObject();
ois.close()
```

Comment: I want to have a dynamic structure that saves items on memory and when its size exceeds some value, save new items on disk until the size goes below the value.

Comment: You need to implement such a structure yourself. A warpper around an ArrayList with wrappers for "add", "remove" and "get" metnods, that do the check you say and serialize and de-serialize as required

Comment: The requirement is quite specific so I doubt an implementation exists that does exactly what you want. As suggested above, writing your own List implementation using an internal ArrayList and object serialization sounds like the best plan. Note that you'll have to implement *all* the List methods, not just add, remove and get.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to change data in this ArrayList often, changing disk image, then why not consider something like http://www.hibernate.org/ ? Well, it is much more complicated than ArrayList but also gives more featues.

Comment: I want to have a dynamic structure that saves items on memory and when its size exceeds some value, save new items on disk until the size goes below the value.

Answer (score 2):

Just to make the set of answers complete :)

[XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)

> XStream is a simple library to
>   serialize objects to XML and back
>   again.

```
Person joe = new Person("Joe", "Walnes");
joe.setPhone(new PhoneNumber(123, "1234-456"));
joe.setFax(new PhoneNumber(123, "9999-999"));
```

Now, to convert it to XML, all you have to do is make a simple call to XStream:

```
String xml = xstream.toXML(joe);
```

The resulting XML looks like this:

```
<person>
  <firstname>Joe</firstname>
  <lastname>Walnes</lastname>
  <phone>
    <code>123</code>
    <number>1234-456</number>
  </phone>
  <fax>
    <code>123</code>
    <number>9999-999</number>
  </fax>
</person>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://jakarta.apache.org/jcs/. This provides a way to manage objects on disk and ram. Another possible solution may to use http://code.google.com/p/pcollections/

Answer (score 1):

MapDB ([mapdb.org](http://www.mapdb.org/)) is a library that persists java objects to disk in various collections: Sets, Maps, Queues.

It supports caching so you can have your most frequent items in memory.

Answer (score 1):

see https://dzone.com/articles/a-filebasedcollection-in-java-for-big-collections

```
try(FileBasedCollection<Integer> fbc = new FileBasedCollection<>()) {
  for(int i = 1; i < 1000_000; i++) {
    fbc.add(i);
  }
  long sum = 0;
  try(FileBasedIterator<Integer> iter = fbc.iterator()) {
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
      Integer i = iter.next();
      sum += i;
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  System.out.println("sum: " + sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of saving stuff which has the advantage of being language and transport neutral is to use Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).